# Умножение узла (Node)

Tags: java

Мне нужно умножить узел (Node) в таком порядке: получаемый узел это 1 2 3 4 5 а узел после выполнения метода имеет такой вид 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5.
Написал метод: выдаёт бесконечный узел который увеличивается сам по себе. При этом предыдущее действие перед распечаткой завершилось. Как мне решить данную задачу?

Код входит в бесконечный цикл:

```
public static void tr12(Node<Integer> n1) {
    Node<Integer> p = n1;
    while (p.hasNext()) {
        p = p.getNext();
    }
    Node<Integer> p2 = new Node<Integer>(n1.getValue(), n1.getNext());
    while (p2 != null) {
        Node<Integer> temp = new Node<Integer>(p2.getValue());
        p.setNext(temp);
        p = p.getNext();
        p2 = p2.getNext();
    }
    print(p2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы каждый раз добавляете элемент в конец, берёте следующий и повторяете бесконечно этот цикл.

1. Нужно перед началом всех этих добавлений запомнить последний элемент.
2. В цикле по добавлению элементов проверять текущий элемент на равенство с тем последним. Это будет условием выхода.

   ```
   public static void tr12(Node<Integer> n1) {
       Node<Integer> p = n1;
       while (p.hasNext()) {
           p = p.getNext();
       }

       Node<Integer> pLast = p;

       Node<Integer> p2 = new Node<Integer>(n1.getValue(), n1.getNext());
       while (p2 != null) {
           Node<Integer> temp = new Node<Integer>(p2.getValue());
           p.setNext(temp);
           p = p.getNext();

           if (p2 == mPlast)
               break;

           p2 = p2.getNext();
       }
       print(p2);
   }
   ```